# Why does `git status` say `Changed but not updated` but `git pull` says `Already up-to-date`?

Tags: git

Why does `git status` say `Changed but not updated` but `git pull` says `Already up-to-date`?

E.g.

```
$ git st
# On branch develop
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   roles/role-A (new commits)
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[snowcrash@snow ansible-playbooks]$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Is `roles/` a submodule?

Comment: Yes, it is. Still not sure how that changes things.

Comment: because you made changes locally, but you have nothing to pull

Comment: So, presumably, as long as I don't add/commit that file then pushing the branch should have no effect (i.e. no files get pushed to the remote).

Comment: after you made changes, you can stage them, commit and push, but pull just get information from remote and see that you already have these info.

Comment: pull can be done if your local branch is behind of remote

Comment: A submodule is a separate Git repository. Your current Git repository records *which commit to check out* in the other (submodule) repository. That's why it changes things.

Answer (score 0):

A parent repo with a submodule records a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the main repo)

Since new commits have been done in the nested repo `roles/role-A`, git status mentions that the gitlink `roles/role-A`

If that same gitlink (which is a reference to a SHA1 of the sub-repo) has not changed remotely, you can do a git pull (that will update other files, but not the `roles/role-A` gitlink)

If nothing has changed remotely, a git pull would say "up-to-date", even if you had tons of modification/commits locally, in your main repo or in your sub-repo.